# Insert Data to Oracle DB table from SQL Server Table with dblink with using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, dblink

I have an table in Oracle named `HR.ST_ADISYON_DETAY`. I can send select command and get data from there such as

`SELECT TOP 100 * FROM OPENQUERY([HBT_CONNECTION] , 'select * from HR.ST_ADISYON_DETAY ORDER BY TARIH DESC');`

I created dblink. My dblink name is HBT_CONNECTION. I want to delete all data from table and insert new data to this Oracle database table. But I couldn't find query to do it. How can I delete and insert statement with db link. I will write it in SQL Server.

```
INSERT INTO HR.ST_ADISYON_DETAY(SICIL_KOD,AD_SOYAD,URUN,MIKTAR,BIRIM_FIYAT,TOPLAM,TARIH) SELECT SICIL_KOD,AD_SOYAD,URUN,MIKTAR,BIRIM_FIYAT,TOPLAM,TO_DATE(TARIH,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') FROM VIEW_HARCAMA_BYSICIL
```

Select part is from SQL Server. Insert part is from Oracle database.

Comment: Try this: delete from HBT_CONNECTION..HR.ST_ADISYON_DETAY. Use uppercase in names and two dots between link name and schema name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM  HBT_CONNECTION..HR.ST_ADISYON_DETAYF

INSERT  INTO HBT_CONNECTION..HR.ST_ADISYON_DETAY(SICIL_KOD,AD_SOYAD,URUN,MIKTAR,BIRIM_FIYAT,TOPLAM,TARIH)
SELECT  SICIL_KOD,AD_SOYAD,URUN,MIKTAR,BIRIM_FIYAT,TOPLAM,TO_DATE(TARIH,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
FROM    VIEW_HARCAMA_BYSICIL
```